# Codeigniter Shopping Cart with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, cart

I am having a problem with Ajax and the CodeIgniter shopping cart. The code works well without AJAX. It seems I am unable to post.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul.products form').submit(function(){

      $('#noticeMessages').empty(); 
        var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();  

  $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url:'../books/addProduct',
          data:{id:id}
          }).done(function(data){

              $('#noticeMessages').append('Your product has been added').css('visibility','visible').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut(5000);
              location.reload();

          });
          return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shopping cart in jquery with php and session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888475/shopping-cart-in-jquery-with-php-and-session)

Comment: check this tutorial for ajax shopping cart with CI really nice http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-shopping-cart/?search_index=1

Comment: Check the URL to which you are posting. Use some kind of dev tools withing the browser: Chrome - Developer Tools (F12), Firefox - Install Firebug Add-on

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems to be a dead question but i still felt like giving my suggestion. Here is what i would do

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('ul.products form').submit(function(){

          $('#noticeMessages').empty(); 
           var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();  
          $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url:'../books/addProduct',
              data:{id:id},
              success:function(data){
                $('#noticeMessages').append('Your product has been added').css('visibility','visible').fadeIn('fast').fadeOut(5000);
                  location.reload();
              }
             });
        });
    </script
```